# Only show the last user response in a survey

Tags: survey

Sorry if this is a bit basic.
I have created a survey and would the users to be able to respond up to a certain date.  I then want to analyse the data.

I can see how it is done, but my question is:

Is it possible to only save the latest response from each user? So if a user revisits the survey it updates the results and only shows as one response.